# How to connect to remote server?

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, connection

I want to connect to a remote server.

Before this command worked perfectly : 
`ssh -i vpsMain root@163.xxx.xxx.xxx`

I need to connecto a other server on this VPS and beacause I've this error when I tried to connect it on VPS :`Provided Host header is not whitelisted``

I do this following command to add host of my server into whitelist of my remote server :

`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s ip addresse -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -d ip addresse -j ACCEPT`

After this when I do `telnet 163.xxx.xxx.xxx` i've `connection refused`

So I wanted to remove iptables actions and do on the remote server :
`iptables -P INPUT DROP`

After this the remote server crash.
I now when I want to connect to it with this command :

`ssh -i vpsMain root@163.xxx.xxx.xxx`it doesn't work and have this error :`ssh: connect to host 163.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out`

Can someone help me?

Comment: There was no any crash, you disabled all network traffic with one command. Do a reboot!

Comment: @IporSircer, how can I reboot if I can access to the VPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have locked yourself out of your system, you have several options depending upon circumstance

- If you have access to the system via an OOB console, use that to log in and fix/restart the system
- If you have access via a hosting providers control panel then use that to restart the system
- Contact your hosting provider and get them to restart the system

Comment: ok thank you! But it's the command `iptables -P INPUT DROP`witch dot this?

Comment: You need to study IP networking and firewall principles on the internet before you are able to manage your VPS firewall in a good way. This is not a site for teaching fundamentals.